# How to Intentionally Create a Long-Running MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, testing

I know this is an odd question to ask, but I'd like to find out if there is a MySQL query I can create without already having millions of rows in my database that will consume resources and run for a long time.  My ultimate goal is to test my application in cases of resource contention and make sure that my methods for handling failure (specifically server timeout) are correct.

If there another way I can test this without creating and executing a high-resource query, I'd appreciate hearing that as well.

Comment: @Nix - in the tens of thousands or so

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I assume you could use `benchmark()` for this, although that isn't the scope of it.

```
select benchmark(9999999999, md5('when will it end?'));
```

Comment: this works perfectly, although I think I can hear my CPU softly weeping under the strain

Comment: because of MySQL (and MariaDB) specifics, this only eats up one CPU core per such query, so you will have major problems when your DB server has only 1 core

Answer (score 4):

If you need them to run for a bit, but not *that* long, then try

```
select benchmark(1000000, md5('when will it end?')); -- around 0.3s
select benchmark(10000000, md5('when will it end?')); -- around 3s
select benchmark(100000000, md5('when will it end?')); -- around 30s
```

Comment: Is there any function which will run my SELECT statement multiple times? I already have a lot of rows and would like to know how long that takes, or does this emulate the same?

Answer (score 2):

For those wondering how to achieve a similar operation for MS SQL Server (not MySQL), use `WAITFOR DELAY '02:00'` if you want to test timeouts.

Comment: Sorry, it's Friday and I strung out.  This is, of course, MS SQL.