# sqlalchemy: stopping a long-running query

Tags: python, django, sqlalchemy, postgresql

I have a seemingly straight-forward situation, but can't find a straight-forward solution.

I'm using sqlalchemy to query postgres.  If a client timeout occurs, I'd like to stop/cancel the long running postgres queries from another thread.  The thread has access to the Session or Connection object.

At this point I've tried:

```
session.bind.raw_connection().close()
```

and

```
session.connection().close()
```

and

```
session.close
```

and

```
session.transaction.close()
```

But no matter what I try, the postgres query still continues until it's end.  I know this from watching pg in top.  Shouldn't this be fairly easy to do?  I'm I missing something?  Is this impossible without getting the pid and sending a stop signal directly?

Comment: Even if you kill your client process entirely, the database may take a long time to roll back its query, depending on what it is and how much data is in the table.  Work on optimizing your queries instead of trying to figure out how to abort them.

Comment: Yes, optimization is most important, but due to the nature of our project timeouts are going to happen and we'd like to make sure we're covering all bases.  Thanks for your comment.

Comment: The way to access the raw socket, to close it, will be buried somewhere in the psycopg2 driver.  You'll have to review the source for it to find this.  Be fully prepared for unexplainable behavior and hard crashes at the sqlalchemy layer, starting the instant you actually force-close one of the sockets.

Comment: Thanks wberry, I was able to get to a working solution with your help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This seems to work well, so far:

```
def test_close_connection(self):
    import threading
    from psycopg2.extensions import QueryCanceledError
    from sqlalchemy.exc import DBAPIError

    session = Session()
    conn = session.connection()
    sql = self.get_raw_sql_for_long_query()

    seconds = 5
    t = threading.Timer(seconds, conn.connection.cancel)
    t.start()

    try:
        conn.execute(sql)
    except DBAPIError, e:
        if type(e.orig) == QueryCanceledError:
            print 'Long running query was cancelled.'
    t.cancel()
```

[source](http://marcelomartinovic.files.wordpress.com/2011/04/python_posgresql1.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

Found on MYSQL that you can specify the query optimiser hints.
One such hint is `MAX_EXECUTION_TIME` to specify how long query should execute before termination.

You can add this in your app.py

```
@event.listens_for(engine, 'before_execute', retval=True)
def intercept(conn, clauseelement, multiparams, params):
  from sqlalchemy.sql.selectable import Select

  # check if it's select statement
  if isinstance(clauseelement, Select):
    # 'froms' represents list of tables that statement is querying
    table = clauseelement.froms[0]
    '''Update the timeout here in ms (1s = 1000ms)'''
    timeout_ms = 4000
    # adding filter in clause
    clauseelement = clauseelement.prefix_with(f"/*+ MAX_EXECUTION_TIME({timeout_ms}) */", dialect="mysql")

  return clauseelement, multiparams, params
```

[SQLAlchemy query API not working correctly with hints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56030825/sqlalchemy-query-api-not-working-correctly-with-hints) and
[MYSQL reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimizer-hints.html)

Answer (score 0):

For those MySQL folks that may have ended up here, a modified version of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9439098/10682164) answer that kills the query from a second connection can work. Essentially the following, assuming pymysql under the hood:

```
thread_id = conn1.connection.thread_id()
t = threading.Timer(seconds, lambda: conn2.execute("kill {}".format(thread_id)))
```

The original connection will raise pymysql.err.OperationalError. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3892443/10682164) other answer for a neat way to create a long running query for testing.