# SQLAlchemy query API not working correctly with hints

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to use the query API to create a MySQL query with the the MAX_EXECUTION_TIME(30000) hint.

My code is roughly:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

class MyTable(SQLAlchemy().Model):
  ...

base_query = Sqlalchemy.session.query(MyTable) # This works when I execute it.
base_query_with_hint = base_query.with_hint(MyTable, "MAX_EXECUTION_TIME(30000)")
base_query_with_hint.execute() # THIS DOES NOT WORK.

str(base_query_with_hint) 
# Output
# Select a, b, c from MyTable MAX_EXECUTION_TIME(30000)
```

The hint is just rendered at the end of the query, apparently!

It should render as

```
Select /*+ MAX_EXECUTION_TIME(30000) */ a, b, c from MyTable
```

I want it to behave exactly like https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.Select.with_hint but I'm using the Query API instead of the Select API.

Comment: I see MySQL has two types of hints, [Index Hints](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/index-hints.html), and [Optimizer Hints](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimizer-hints.html). Your hint is an optimizer hint, and needs to use the comment syntax as you've got above, but perhaps its being treated as an Index Hint, and rendering as part of the query. So if that's true, the real question is can `with_hint()` be coerced to render an optimizer hint for mysql?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your query, if you compile it using the oracle dialect it outputs the way that the documentation illustrates, but obviously wrong dialect for you. `from sqlalchemy.dialects import oracle; print(base_query_with_hint.statement.compile(dialect=oracle.dialect()))` outputs `SELECT /*+ MAX_EXECUTION_TIME(30000) */ mytable.a...`.

Comment: I searched github issues and mailing list for terms like 'mysql with_hint', 'mysql optimizer' etc and couldn't see anything relevant, so perhaps a good question for the [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/sqlalchemy).

Comment: It would be good if you could draft an answer based on the feedback from the mailing list as it's a novel question.

Answer (score 0):

In short, use `prefix_with()` instead.

Here's a similar example for MySQL 5.7 optimizer hints from [SQLAlchemy documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.Select.prefix_with), running in a Python interactive prompt:

```
>>> from sqlalchemy.sql import select, table
>>> from sqlalchemy.dialects import mysql
>>> tbl = table('my_table')
>>> # MySQL 5.7 optimizer hints
>>> stmt = select([tbl]).prefix_with(
...     "/*+ MAX_EXECUTION_TIME(1000) */", dialect="mysql")
>>> print(stmt.compile(dialect=mysql.dialect()))
SELECT /*+ MAX_EXECUTION_TIME(1000) */  
FROM my_table
>>>
```