# Query Job Configuration and Query Job Accessing in SQLAlchemy-BigQuery

Tags: python, google-bigquery, sqlalchemy

I'm migrating tasks managing BigQuery tables from using Google's BigQuery Python client library to their SQLAlchemy plugin for BigQuery dialect. There are several issues during migration of some of the logics:

1. Query configuration -- in the original Python client, user can pass in a configuration instance (e.g., `QueryJobConfig`, `LoadJobConfig`, etc.) when issuing query through client instance. From SQLAlchemy plugin's documentation, it allows you to pass in configuration information during `Engine` instance initialization, but nothing mentioned when it comes to running query through `Connection.execute()`, `Session.query()`, or other methods alike. Is it possible to pass in query configuration like the client library do when issuing queries through SQLAlchemy Core/ORM?

   **Example 1**:
   Say I want to query against some dataset within location `us-west1`, but my default location setup is `us-west3`. Also I want to timeout when there's no response within a minute. In the original library, I can pass the location information when calling `Clinet.query()`, and set up timeout when running the job through `result()` --

   ```py
   from google.cloud import bigquery

   client = bigquery.Client(project='my-project-id', location='us-west3')
   query_job = client.query('SELECT id, name FROM my_dataset.my_table;', location='us-west1')
   result_set = query_job.result(timeout=60)
   ```

   But native SQLAlchemy doesn't provide these options when issuing queries.

   **Example 2:**
   I want to label a query job through `QueryJobConfig`, so that later I can query analytics of similar jobs from system table.

   ```py
   from google.cloud import bigquery

   client = bigquery.Client(project='my-project-id', location='us-west3')
   config = bigquery.job.QueryJobConfig(labels={"query_category": "common"})
   query_job = client.query('SELECT id, name FROM my_dataset.my_table;', job_config=config, location='us-west1')
   result_set = query_job.result()
   ```

   Again, the SQLAlchemy plugin didn't mention how to pass in the configuration when issuing queries. From documentation the only place where you can set up job config is [`create_engine ()`](https://github.com/googleapis/python-bigquery-sqlalchemy#connection-string-parameters) for providing default job settings.
2. Accessing underlying query job instance, or at least job ID during query execution.

   For example, if under some circumstance I need to cancel a query job, with the original Python client I can simply call [`cancel()`](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/bigquery/latest/google.cloud.bigquery.job.QueryJob#google_cloud_bigquery_job_QueryJob_cancel) on the job instance, but at dbapi / SQLAlchemy's end I can't do it by just calling `close()` on the connection/cursor instance, because seems that they only mark the connection/cursor as closed without dealing with the ongoing job, from underlying implementation. Hence it would be helpful if it's possible to access query job directly, or get the job ID so I can spin up an native BigQuery client then [grab the details](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/bigquery/latest/google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client#google_cloud_bigquery_client_Client_get_job).

   **Example:** Say I don't want to rely on client library's timeout mechanism, and would want to cancel the request myself. In the client library, you can send cancel request through `QueryJob` instance:

   ```
   from time import sleep

   from google.cloud import bigquery

   client = bigquery.Client(project='my-project-id', location='us-west3')
   long_query = ... # Some long running query
   query_job = client.query(long_query) # With no timeout

   time.sleep(10)
   if not query_job.done():
       query_job.cancel()
   ```

   However, SQLAlchemy [doesn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9437498/sqlalchemy-stopping-a-long-running-query) offer way to cancel a running query, hence you'll need to access underlying job details (either the job instance or job ID) so that you can cancel the query elsewhere.

Comment: Can you provide the sample code you are using and the errors you are getting?

Comment: No, I'm not describing errors I got when using the library. I'm asking for functionality I didn't found when migrating code from the original approach to the new one. I'll provide an example I'm trying to replicate, however.